# Force imap to use index on named vector

Tags: r, purrr

### Simplest reprex and question

I have the simplest named vector in the world, say:

```
vec <- seq(101, 126)
names(vec) <- letters
head(vec)
#  a   b   c   d   e   f 
#101 102 103 104 105 106
```

Now I iterate over it using `purrr::imap`.

```
library(purrr)
vec %>% head %>% imap_chr(~paste(.x, .y, sep="_"))
#      a       b       c       d       e       f 
#"101_a" "102_b" "103_c" "104_d" "105_e" "106_f"
```

This behaviour is completely normal: `.x` iterates over the values, and `.y` iterates over the names (like `names`) if the vector is named, over the indices (like `seq_along`) otherwise.

I want to know if there is a way to behave as if the input vector was NOT named, i.e. having a way to access indices instead of names.
The expected output is:

```
#      a       b       c       d       e       f 
#"101_1" "102_2" "103_3" "104_4" "105_5" "106_6"
```

### Current workaround

I am currently using `purrr::map2` as a workaround, but I don't find this solution elegant (too verbose).

```
vec %>% head %>% {map2_chr(., seq_along(.), ~paste(.x, .y, sep="_"))}
# Or, using Darren Tsai's more concise solution:
vec %>% head %>% map2_chr(seq_along(.), paste, sep="_")
#      a       b       c       d       e       f 
#"101_1" "102_2" "103_3" "104_4" "105_5" "106_6"
```

---

## Addendum

The problem with providing a very simple reprex is that people try to solve my problem instead of answering my question. That's super kind, but not what I'm looking for. My issue is **not** to concatenate `.x` and `.y`.

### More elaborate reprex

Let's say I have the following distance matrix between some observations:

```
mat <- matrix(c(0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 4, 2, 4, 0), 3, 3)
nms <- letters[seq(3)]
names(nms) <- nms # Without this, I could use imap
dimnames(mat) <- list(nms, nms)
mat
#  a b c
#a 0 1 2
#b 1 0 4
#c 2 4 0
```

Now I want to know the standard deviation of the distances of each observation with others. I could try with `imap`, but `colnames(mat)` is a named vector itself:

```
colnames(mat) %>% imap_dbl(~sd(mat[-.y,.x]))
#Error in -.y : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Right now, I'm tackling this issue by using `map2`.

```
colnames(mat) %>% map2_dbl(seq_along(.), ~sd(mat[-.y,.x]))
#[1] 0.7071068 2.1213203 1.4142136
```

Comment: Your `map2` workaround can be simplified a little to `%>% map2_chr(seq_along(.), ~ paste(.x, .y, sep="_"))` or more concise `%>% map2_chr(seq_along(.), paste, sep="_")`.

Comment: What about: `vec[] <- paste0(vec, "_", seq_along(vec))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct answer here is that `imap` (as of August 2023) cannot perform this behavior. The reason is the way that `imap` is written.

```
> imap
function (.x, .f, ...) 
{
    .f <- as_mapper(.f, ...)
    map2(.x, vec_index(.x), .f, ...)
}
<bytecode: 0x564de0b0eb08>
<environment: namespace:purrr>
```

Under the hood `imap` is also doing the same `map2` trick.

And when you inspect the `vec_index()` function...

```
> purrr:::vec_index
function (x) 
{
    names(x) %||% seq_along(x)
}
<bytecode: 0x564de0afaad0>
<environment: namespace:purrr>
```

The `%||%` function is probably unfamiliar and comes from `rlang`:

```
> `%||%`
function (x, y) 
{
    if (is_null(x)) 
        y
    else x
}
<bytecode: 0x564ddd79c4a8>
<environment: namespace:rlang>
```

The sum of all of this is that `imap` as currently implemented will attempt to capture `names(x)` where x is the input vector. If this is `NULL` (i.e. no name) *only then* will it capture the index position (using `seq_along(x)`). Thus if your input vector is named, at no point will the index be calculated and consequently be available for the input function `.f`.

We could imagine a sort of `ipmap` which uses `pmap` under the hood and at initialization would capture both the names and index and you can access either or both of these within each iteration. It sounds like this [was considered](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/678) but currently there's no plan to do so. You could of course write your own version to do this but that has drawbacks.

Taking your second example, you could of course try something trivial like using `unname` on the input vector to force it to use indices.

```
> colnames(mat) %>% unname() %>% imap_dbl(~sd(mat[-.y,.x]))
[1] 0.7071068 2.1213203 1.4142136
```

However your output vector is also now no longer named. While we're being inelegant we can just append the names to the vector output, but I have no idea if this works for your actual use case.

```
> colnames(mat) %>% unname() %>% imap_dbl(~sd(mat[-.y,.x])) %>% purrr::set_names(colnames(mat))
        a         b         c 
0.7071068 2.1213203 1.4142136
```

Comment: Interesting take, thanks! I don't remember what my actual use case was, but your solutions are definitely worth mentioning, and your investigation is definitely answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `imap` a work-around would be to use `match`

```
library(purrr)
vec %>% imap_chr(~paste(.x, match(.y, names(vec)), sep="_")) %>% head

#     a       b       c       d       e       f 
#"101_1" "102_2" "103_3" "104_4" "105_5" "106_6"
```

---

We can also use `map_chr` iterating over its index.

```
vec[] <- seq_along(vec) %>% map_chr(~paste(vec[.x], .x, sep = "_"))
head(vec)

#     a       b       c       d       e       f 
#"101_1" "102_2" "103_3" "104_4" "105_5" "106_6"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_c` with `imap`

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
vec %>% 
    imap_chr(~ str_c(.x, match(.y, names(vec)), sep="_"))
```